# Want to Control my Internet Speed

Tags: windows-7, internet, speed

I want to control my bandwidth. Is there any way to control my Internet speed? I just want control my net speed. Please suggest any type of software or manual setting on Windows 7. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your router supports QoS, you can limit your connection using QoS among other things.

If you want to do it on windows directly, you can use software like http://www.netlimiter.com/ or similar.

Comment: Can i set bandwidth for the particular website for every time when i start the system. i set the limit for a site but when i closed the browser it's process closed automatically.